# stored procedure inserts truncated value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that uses several input parameters and insert them into Sql Database. There is a problem with one parameter, @CustomerId, that is truncated (but not always) when inserted into database.

**C#:**

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", Convert.ToInt32(customerId));
cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
sqlConn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConn.Close();
```

**Sql SP:**
@CustomerId int

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblOffers 
(CustomerId)
VALUES
    (@CustomerId)
```

**sql table datatype:**

```
CustomerId int not null
```

Example: 564276117 truncated to 4276117 (but its not happening all the time, and there are values greater than 560000000 that are inserted properly) 
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(customerId)`... Is `customerId` not already an `int`?  If it's treated as a `string` throughout the rest of the code then maybe it's being truncated before it even gets here?

Comment: You should have to change the field datatype of CustomerId to bigint.

Comment: @AVD - `564276117` is within the bounds of an `int`.

Comment: I have thought too about bigint, but I have checked the int data type and it is fine for my values range.

Comment: no, in debug mode the "customerid" parameter is not truncated, however in production enviroment its sometimes truncated - is it relevant that in development environment I work with Sql Srv 2008 and in production with 2005?

Comment: It may or may not be the problem in this instance, but in general it is an extremly poor practice to develop against a database that is a higher version than production, This is a practice you shoudl immediately stop.

Comment: In your C# code, what is the type of the "customerId" variable that you are performing the convert upon? I'm assuming it is a string or some numeric type, but it would be helpful to know for sure. David makes a good point above. Is there anything before this block of code that could affect the value of this variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Parameters.Add()` method instead of `AddWithValue`.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId",SqlDbType.Int).Value=CustomerID;
```

Comment: it is ok, not sure if this problem will not repeat with this changed approach

Comment: another example, 563280137, is stored ok, in the same conditions (nothing changed). why that?

Answer (score -1):

Would you please try as below: using `ToInt64`

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", Convert.ToInt64(customerId));
cmd.Connection = sqlConn;
sqlConn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConn.Close();
```

Comment: its working fine with int32 in development environment, debug mode

Comment: The values he is using are within the upper bounds of int32 already.